# Ethernet cable is blinking all except 6 LED in the tester

Tags: networking

I bought a new 20 meter cable, and I noticed a problem where it connects and then disconnects in Windows. I tried another short original cable and it worked fine. So I tried the 20m cable on a tester and found the number 6 LED not flashing.

I bought all the needed stuff to fix the cable and changed the two RJ connectors, but still the 6 LED is not flashing, although working on the short cable. Is the problem in the cable, especially that I can see the cable not having "Orange/white" color and replaced with Black.

Any help ?

Comment: "I can see the cable not having "Orange/white" color and replaced with Black" – that's a bit odd for something sold as an Ethernet cable; is the black wire still twisted together with orange or is it separate? what are the other wires like? what's written on the cable itself?

Comment: It could be a bad cable or bad twist inside (assuming ends to be correct). Replace the cable with a known good one. I am looking a my own tester.

Comment: Why didn't you just send it back & get it swapped for a good one? You've now wasted money on cable, tooling & spare components & you still have a non-working cable that you're going to have to buy again.